# ClassNotFoundException while decomissioning executor's rdd blocks via SIGPWR (graceful decommision)

Tags: apache-spark

I'm testing a spark's "graceful decommission" feature for rdd blocks in kubernetes and getting an exception after sending a sigpwr signal to the executor.

```
21/06/11 04:04:34 INFO TransportClientFactory: Found inactive connection to /10.108.14.4:46813, creating a new one.
21/06/11 04:04:34 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /10.108.14.4:46813 after 2 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
21/06/11 04:04:34 ERROR NettyBlockTransferService: Error while uploading rdd_26_7 as stream
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.haodemon.processing.data.LogContainer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:68)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer.deserializeMetadata(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer.receiveStream(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processStreamUpload(TransportRequestHandler.java:200)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:207)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:142)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
```

Parameters in spark-defaults:

```
spark.decommission.enabled: true
spark.storage.decommission.enabled: true
spark.storage.decommission.rddBlocks.enabled: true
spark.storage.decommission.shuffleBlocks.enabled: true
```

The executor process in ps:

```
185        31924  166  3.9 26408928 5186056 ?    Sl   04:20   1:21  
/usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java \
    -Dspark.driver.port=40577 \
    -D spark.ui.port=4196 \
    -Dspark.history.ui.port=18080 \
    -Xms17408m \
    -cp /opt/spark/conf:/opt/spark/jars/*:/opt/jars/my.jar \
    org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend \
    --driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@<hostname>:40577 \
    --executor-id 8 \
    --cores 5 \
    --app-id spark-application-1623385214993 \
    --hostname 10.108.9.30 \
    --resourceProfileId 0
```

In the executor's classpath, the jar /opt/jars/my.jar contains the missing class.

```
$ jar tf /opt/jars/my.jar | grep LogContainer
com.haodemon.processing.data.LogContainer
```

Spark version is 3.1.2 and the docker image is an unmodified image in `kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile` (openjdk:11-jre-slim).

Do I miss something here? Thanks.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by putting my jars right into the Spark's image (/jars directory). This is not ideal but it works for now.